# Chrome Browser v35 No Sound

Tags: sound, google-chrome

I have chrome 35 and firefox 28 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 OS. Unfortunately, I have no sound when viewing youtube or a website with video using chrome. With firefox I have sound. I would like to use Chrome for my kiosk application. Can anyone offer some help to get sound to work on Chrome?

Comment: Open system settings, click sound and then the applications tab. Can you see chrome in the list, when it is playing sound (e.g. youtube?)

Comment: Chrome 37, no sound 12.04?!?

Comment: Did you play sound throguh HDNMI recently? See my comment here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/511385/no-sound-on-any-web-browser