# No sound on any web browser

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, hdmi

I was using my laptop to play Youtube on my TV.  I had no problems.  It was going through my HDMI and I was using the cable to play sound through the TV.  I disconnected the cable and since then there is no sound.

The sound card is working because I get the welcome tone when I get my password screen.

I have tried to use Firefox and Chrome and nothing.  I have restarted and rebooted and nothing.

I have checked my sound settings and they are all ok.

Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS.  Latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.

If you need any other info please ask.

UPDATE - not working on VLC media player either...

Comment: Ok it appears to working now but for no reason at all!  All I did was open the speaker options and screen cap it for a friend to see and it started working all by itself...  I really have no idea why it started to work all of sudden... computer glich?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: When I re-insert the HDMI cable, the sound plays through the TV, though the analog card is marked in the sound menu. Marking the HDMI output, then the analog output makes it play through laptop speakers. Then disconnecting the HDMI makes Firefox play through play through laptop speakers again...