# Audio is not working with any browswer (but working with other applications)

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome

The audio is not working in both Firefox and Chrome but it works fine with other applications like VLC. I'm unable to hear videos from any site (YouTube, Coursera, etc.)

I've referred the following:

- [Mozilla Support: Fix common audio and video issues](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Videos-sound-pictures-and/Fix-common-audio-and-video-issues/ta-p/401#w_you-may-need-to-install-the-required-pulseaudio-software) (I already have PulseAudio installed)
- [No sound on any web browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511385/no-sound-on-any-web-browser) (note that this post has the problem with VLC audio too)
- [Launchpad: Ubuntu 11.10 Audio Problems with Browsers](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/858466)

But none of it gives a concrete solution to the problem.

Is there a simple solution for this problem?

Version: 14.04 LTS